# Styling PHP with CSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Sorry if this is a bit dumb but I have never dabbled with PHP before.

Basically I am using a premium wordpress theme called Kingsize, which is beautiful but does not have the author displayed on a post. I have managed to get it in there, on the individual post (by editing single.php) and the post list (loop.php).

I guess I did that sort of right because it is appearing in there. Problem is in both instances it is on the line beneath the date and I want it on same line:

http://bathastronomers.co.uk/category/bath-astronomers/

I thought I could figure it out if I found "post_date" in the style.css but it doesn't appear to be there!

Also, I want rid of the little icons before date and author.

Any ideas?

Here's the relevant code in single.php:

```
<?php 
if( $data['wm_date_enabled'] == '1' ) { //data is enabled
?>
<div class="metadata">
        <p class="post_date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format'));?></p> 
                                 <p class="post_author"><?php the_author(); ?></p>
         </div> 
        <?php}
?>
```

Comment: Putting it simply PHP is a server side language, that the client doesn't see, therefore it has no styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:

```
<div class="metadata">
    <p>
    <span class="post_date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format'));?></span> 
    <span class="post_author"><?php the_author(); ?></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That is great! Thank you very much. Saved me so much time.

Comment: Pro-tip for next time: In Google Chrome, you can right click on any element and select "Inspect Element" to see the outputted markup for any element, including the IDs and classes. This will help you figure out what you can hook into for styling.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the author to appear on the same line as the Date, add this to your style.css :

```
.post .metadata p.post_date {
float:left;
}
```

If you want to hide the small icon on the left, modify the following :

```
.post .metadata p {
padding: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
background: url("images/calendar.png") no-repeat scroll left -1px transparent;
}
```

For the following :

```
.post .metadata p {
padding: 0px;    
}
```

Note that you don't "style PHP". You style HTML. To put it simply, PHP is a HTML generator.